# Parse a substring in Python using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse a substring using re.

From the string present in variable *s*,I would like to split the string present till the first **!**(the string stored in s has two **!**) and store it as a substring.From this substring(stored in variable *result*), I wish to parse another substring.

Here is the code,

```
import re
s='ecNumber*2.4.1.11#kmValue*0.57#kmValueMaximum*1.25#!ecNumber*2.3.1.11#kmValue*0.081#kmValueMaximum*#!'


Data={}

result = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % ('ec', '!'), s).group(1)
print result
ecNumber = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % ('Number*', '#kmValue*'), result).group(1)
Data["ecNumber"]=ecNumber
print Data
```

The value corresponding to each tag present in the substring(example:ecNumber)  is stored in between * and # (example: *2.4.1.11#).I attempted to parse the value stored for the tag *ecNumber* in the first substring.
The output I obtain is

```
result='Number*2.4.1.11#kmValue*0.57#kmValueMaximum*1.25#!ecNumber*2.3.1.11#kmValue*0.081#kmValueMaximum*#'
{'ecNumber': '*2.4.1.11#kmValue*0.57#kmValueMaximum*1.25#!ecNumber*2.3.1.11#kmValue*0.081'}
```

The desired output is

```
result= 'ecNumber*2.4.1.11#kmValue*0.57#kmValueMaximum*1.25#'
{'ecNumber': '2.4.1.11'}
```

I would like to store each tag and its corresponding value.For example,

```
{'ecNumber': '2.4.1.11','kmValue':'0.021','kmValueMaximum':'1.25'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite you are asking a solution with regular expression, I would say it's much easier to use direct string operations for this problem, since the source string is well formatted.

For infomation before the first `i`:

```
print dict([i.split('*') for i in s.split('!', 1)[0].split('#') if i])
```

For all information in `s`:

```
print [dict([i.split('*') for i in j.split('#') if i]) for j in s.split('!') if j]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting this wonderful alternative.Could you please give some advice on how to loop through each substring? i.e  substring1=ecNumber*2.4.1.11#kmValue*0.57#kmValueMaximum*1.25# substring2=ecNumber*2.3.1.11#kmValue*0.081#kmValueMaximum*#

Comment: I tried the following,but didn't work                                                                                           
    'substring=[0]*2
    for j,i in zip(range(0,2),range(0,2)):
    substring[j]= dict([i.split('*') for i in s.split('!', j)[0].split('#') if i])
    print substring'

Comment: `s.split('!', j)` should be `s.split('!', 1)`

Comment: From your original question, you only need infomation before the first `!`. If you need all information, try `print [dict([i.split('*') for i in j.split('#') if i]) for j in s.split('!') if j]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
s='ecNumber*2.4.1.11#kmValue*0.57#kmValueMaximum*1.25#' 
new_data = re.findall('(?<=^)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\*)|(?<=#)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\*)|(?<=\*)[-\d\.]+(?=#)', s)
final_data = dict([new_data[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(new_data)-1, 2)])
```

Output:

```
{'kmValue': '0.57', 'kmValueMaximum': '1.25', 'ecNumber': '2.4.1.11'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Could you please tell how to use the above for parsing kmValue ({'kmValue ': '-999'}?I tried altering the index of new_data.But it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much.